# Display a line in color with PHP

Tags: php, css

I would like to ask you how to display a line (which belongs to a plugin datagrid) in color according to a specific condition.
I have made that :

```
$data = $mysqli->query($sqlf);      
while($dnseuil = $data->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $color = $dnseuil["st"]<=$dnseuil["tp"] ? '#FF0000' : ''; 
    $classe = $dnseuil["st"]<=$dnseuil["tp"] ? '#FFFFFF' : ''; 
    echo '<td bgcolor="' . $color . '"
    style = "background-color:' . $color . ';" 
    class = "'.$classe.'"
    data-st = "'.$dnseuil["st"].'"  
    data-tp = "'.$dnseuil["tp"].'">'; 
}
```

My SQL request works and the problem is that when the quantity of st is less than the quantity of tp, I would like to display the concerned line in red.
Do you have solutions ?
Thanks !

Comment: You could use the [`color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color) css property?

Comment: Why are you using a color in the class field ? Why are you using `bgcolor` when you should use `style` ?

Comment: looks like it should work, check your conditions carefully

Comment: And you're better off using `'inherit'` or something rather than `''` for the default situation. Otherwise you're introducing errors, which is never a good idea. And you say "less than" in the text, but you're using `<=` in the code; that might be worth looking into.

Comment: I try to use the color css property but I think I'm wrong.
And also style is used here, isn't it ? 
How to use Inherit ?
Thanks for having answered